# Passing list of parameter to Powershell using Ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible, yaml

i have a list of parameter in a YAML file call vars_sb_task.yml:

```
---
type: taskWindows
actions:
  abortActions: []
  emailNotifications: []
  setVariableActions: []
  snmpNotifications: []
  systemOperations: []
agent: test
name: "Test"
summary: "Test"
...
```

I have a Powershell script for stonebranch task creation called sb.ps1:

```
function Stonebrach.Connect {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Sb_uri,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Auth_filename,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Method,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    $Body
)

$basicAuth=Get-Content "C:\$auth_filename"
$headers = @{
        "Authorization" = $basicAuth
        "Content-Type"="application/json"
}
$RSP=$null

try{
    if ( $body -eq $null ) {
        $response = invoke-restmethod -Uri $Sb_uri -Method $Method -Headers $headers
    }
    else {
        $response = invoke-restmethod -Uri $sb_uri -Method $method -Headers $headers -Body **$body**
    }
    return $response
}
catch{
   $RSP = $_.Exception.Message
   return $RSP
}
}

function Stonebranch.Create.Task.Windows {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Sb_base_uri,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Auth_filename,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Method,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Body
)
    Stonebrach.Connect -SB_uri $Sb_base_uri/task -Auth_filename 
$Auth_filename -Method $Method -Body $Body
}
```

i want to call the function like this:

```
$response = Stonebranch.Create.Task.Windows -Sb_base_uri $Sb_base_uri -Auth_filename $Auth_filename -Method POST -Body $body
```

**Here's the question: i want to pass all of the parameter in vars_sb_task.yml into $body, do anyone knows how to do that using Ansible?** Since i intend to push that sb.ps1 into another Windows server using Ansible.

Or you can show me how to pass that yml file using Powershell if there's no way using Ansible. Im pretty new in both field, thanks for your help.

** Edit:
i tried to write a playbook with the vars_sb_task.yml:

```
---
- name: test vars file
  hosts: windows
  vars_files:
   - /home/tung/ansible_test/vars_sb_win_task.yml
  tasks:
  - name: test vars
    debug:
      msg: "{{ agent }}"
```

After i run this playbook, it returns 'test', since my agent have value test. If it is single variable, i can pass it into the Powershell script, but the problem is that i have to pass all variables of the yaml file into $body. I don't know what to do from here. I try to read the Ansible documentation, but it is not really clear. It would be nice if anyone could write an example how to handle and pass these variables in yaml file **into a single variable** in Powershell ($body in this case)

Comment: Use the file and win_shell modules in Ansible. The first to read your file and the second to run your ps

Comment: Can you a bit more specific sir? how to use file module to pass all parameters from that .yml file into the $body in PS script? I would appreciate if you could write some example. I know how to run the PS script on the target nodes.

Comment: I recommend you to read the documentation first - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/file.html

and 

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_shell_module.html

to understand if it fits your requirements. Do you want to add the whole yaml in your body?

Check also variables help - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html

Try to do a small playbook by yourself and share it. From there I will help you.

Comment: here's my playbook:
---
- name: test vars file
  hosts: windows
  vars_files:
   - /home/tung/ansible_test/vars_sb_win_task.yml
  tasks:
  - name: test vars
    debug:
      msg: "{{ agent }}"

After i run this playbook, it returns 'test', since my agent have value test. If it is single variable, i can pass it into the Powershell script, but the problem is that i have to pass all varialbes of the yaml file into $body. I don't know what to do from here. I try to read the documentation as you suggest, but it is not really clear, It would be nice if you could write 1 example for me.

Comment: I will edit more in the post. Please take a look.

Comment: Cool. Last question. Sorry for being so annoying but I want to be sure that you have the right answer. Can you post an example of how your $body should be? Var by var? The whole yaml? Another format? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, you can try something like:

```
---
- name: test vars file
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
   - vars_sb_task.yml
  tasks:

  - name: Add File to var
    set_fact:
      body: "{{ item  }}"
    with_file: "vars_sb_task.yml"

  - name: test vars
    debug:
      msg: "{{ body }}"

  - name: Run PS
    win_shell:  ". script1.ps1; Stonebranch.Create.Task.Windows"
    args: "-Sb_base_uri $Sb_base_uri -Auth_filename $Auth_filename -Method POST -Body {{ body }}"
    register: _out
```

The first part will save your file into the `"{{ body }}"` var. Then you can use it with win_shell (Here it is just an example about how to load the Function in one line). I haven't tested this last part. Test first your command in Windows and then copy into your code with the `body` var.

The result of the body var is:

```
TASK [Add File to var] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=---
type: taskWindows
actions:
  abortActions: []
  emailNotifications: []
  setVariableActions: []
  snmpNotifications: []
  systemOperations: []
agent: test
name: "Test"
summary: "Test")

TASK [test vars] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "---\ntype: taskWindows\nactions:\n  abortActions: []\n  emailNotifications: []\n  setVariableActions: []\n  snmpNotifications: []\n  systemOperations: []\nagent: test\nname: \"Test\"\nsummary: \"Test\""
}
```

Comment: Hi sir, first of all, many thanks for your help. It makes me understand more how to handle Ansible variables. If i read correctly, you create a new body variable inside Ansible playbook with the content of the YAML file, and then pass it into the Powershell script as argument. However, is there anyway to pass the YAML directly into the $body variable inside the Powershell script? That's what i have in mind, and i do not think it is possible from my point of view. Maybe you know another way...

Comment: That is the second option I had in my mind, that’s why my questions. You can use jinja2 and create the powershell as a template and then replace the variables.

Comment: One of my colleague suggest using the Get-AnsibleParam, Do you know how to apply in this case? i read the https://code.vt.edu/nis-ansible-roles/upstream-ansible/blob/2a751e1753c1fe675ba3d0b1dbc9939c9253ea70/lib/ansible/module_utils/powershell.ps1 to learn about this built-in function, but it is not very clear

Comment: Those are part of the Ansible Modules. You can find the Powershell Modules at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/powershell I think is more Kung-Fu adding them first than parsing by yourself.